# Дебаггинг кода с Обфускацией | JavaScript/HTML Debugging

Tags: javascript, discord, javascript-events, обфускация

У меня есть вот такой вот код из 2-х строк для браузерной версии дискорда.

(его нужно запускать из вкладки "/channels/@me")

```js
document.querySelector('.inputDefault-_djjkz.input-cIJ7To.inputInner-2akrSS').value = "https://discord.gg/EFtF2eJC"
document.querySelector('.button-38aScr.lookFilled-1Gx00P.colorBrand-3pXr91.sizeMedium-1AC_Sl.grow-q77ONN').click()
```

Этот код изменяет текст в input и нажимает на кнопку "Присоединиться к серверу".

Но при выполнении кода выпадает ошибка (см на фото 1), при чём если физически мышкой нажать на кнопку - эффект тот же, но если с клавиатуры ввести любой символ, например пробел и также нажать на кнопку или сделать это через click(), то всё успешно срабатывает, как и было задумано.

Соответственно мне бы хотелось напрямую выполнить функцию, которая выполняется по нажатию кнопки или же как-то обмануть код написанный разработчиками дискорда. Но вот беда, через дебаггер я вижу страшные вещи. Выполняется какая-то пустая функция, а весь код забит однобуквенными переменными.

Буду рад любым идям.

[image: 1]

Comment: Значит не зря программистам платят в Дискорде. Используйте другие средства, эмулирующие работу клавиатуры/мышки.